What is the value of $\operatorname{Var}(S^2)$, when $S^2$ is given as sample variance with denominator $n$ instead of $(n-1)$?
At first, this looked like an easy task, starting with usual expression for variance, such as:
$\operatorname{Var}(S^2)= E(S^4) - (E(S^2))^2$. Once again, herein I want to define $S^2=\frac{\sum_1^n (X_i-\bar X)^2}{n}$
$\operatorname{Var}(S^2)= E(S^4) - (E(S^2))^2 = E(S^4) - \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}\sigma^4$
Now, I need to evaluate $E(S^4)$, which is quite challenging for me. My thoughts were the following:
$E(S^4) = E(((\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n(X_i - \bar X)^2)^2)=\frac{1}{n^2}E((\sum_i^n(X_i - \bar X)^2)^2)$  , and then I got lost...

I will assume that $X_i$'s are IID, having finite 4th moment. Note that
\begin{align*}
S^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \overline{X})^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \mu)^2 - (\overline{X} - \mu)^2. 
\end{align*}
In light of this formula, we may replace $X_i-\mu$'s by $X_i$'s and hence can assume $X_i$'s have zero mean without losing the generality. Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[S^4]
&= \mathbf{E}\biggl[ \biggl(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2 - \overline{X}^2 \biggr)^2 \biggr] \\
&=  \mathbf{E}\biggl[ \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i, j} X_i^2 X_j^2 - \frac{2}{n} \sum_i X_i^2 \overline{X}^2 + \overline{X}^4 \biggr] \\
&=  \mathbf{E}\biggl[ \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i, j} X_i^2 X_j^2 - \frac{2}{n^3} \sum_{i,j,k} X_i^2 X_j X_k + \frac{1}{n^4} \sum_{i,j,k,l} X_i X_j X_k X_l \biggr].
\end{align*}
Distributing the expectation using linearity, we are left with bunch of linear combinations of terms of the form $\mathbf{E}[X_{i_1}^{a_1} X_{i_2}^{a_2} \cdots]$ with mutually distinct $i_1, i_2, \ldots$ and $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots = 4$. Then the independence tells that
$$\mathbf{E}[X_{i_1}^{a_1} X_{i_2}^{a_2} \cdots] = \mathbf{E}[X_{i_1}^{a_1}]\mathbf{E}[X_{i_2}^{a_2}] \cdots,$$
and in particular, this term vanishes if at least one of $a_k$'s is $1$. This greatly reduces the number of terms appearing in the expansion. Indeed, the only tuples $(a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ that possibly result non-zero terms are $(2, 2)$ and $(4)$. Hence
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[S^4]
&=  \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i} \mathbf{E}[X^4] + \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i \neq j} \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 \\
&\quad - \frac{2}{n^3} \sum_{i} \mathbf{E}[X^4] - \frac{2}{n^3} \sum_{i \neq j} \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 \\
&\quad + \frac{1}{n^4} \sum_{i} \mathbf{E}[X^4] + \frac{3}{n^4} \sum_{i \neq j} \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 \\
&=  \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot n \mathbf{E}[X^4] + \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot n(n-1) \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 \\
&\quad - \frac{2}{n^3} \cdot n \mathbf{E}[X^4] - \frac{2}{n^3} \cdot n(n-1) \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 \\
&\quad + \frac{1}{n^4} \cdot n \mathbf{E}[X^4] + \frac{3}{n^4} \cdot n(n-1) \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 \\
&=  \frac{n(n-1)^2}{n^4} \mathbf{E}[X^4] + \frac{n(n-1)(n^2 - 2n + 3)}{n^4} \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2.
\end{align*}
In order to complete the computation, note that $\mathbf{E}[S^2] = \frac{n-1}{n} \mathbf{E}[X^2]$. (Recall that we are still assuming $X_i$'s are centered. Otherwise, this formula should become $\mathbf{E}[S^2] = \frac{n-1}{n} \mathbf{Var}(X)$.) Plugging this back,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{Var}(S^2)
&= \mathbf{E}[S^4] - \mathbf{E}[S^2]^2 \\
&= \frac{n(n-1)^2}{n^4} \mathbf{E}[X^4] + \frac{n(n-1)(n^2 - 2n + 3)}{n^4} \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 - \frac{n^2(n-1)^2}{n^4} \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 \\
&= \frac{n(n-1)^2}{n^4} \mathbf{E}[X^4] - \frac{n(n-1)(n-3)}{n^4} \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 \\
&= \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^3} \mu_4(X) - \frac{(n-1)(n-3)}{n^3} \mu_2(X)^2.
\end{align*}
Using the sample variance $\hat{S}^2 = \frac{n}{n-1} S^2$, this formula is usually presented in the form
$$ \mathbf{Var}(\hat{S}^2)
= \frac{n^2}{(n-1)^2} \mathbf{Var}(S^2)
= \frac{1}{n} \biggl( \mu_4(X) - \frac{n-3}{n-1} \mu_2(X)^2 \biggr), $$
see this, for instance.

Wonderful explanation! It has helped me thoroughly @Sangchul Lee.
However, I am wondering how have you formed expectations for each sum in this equation: \begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[S^4]
&=  \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i} \mathbf{E}[X^4] + \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i \neq j} \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 \
&\quad - \frac{2}{n^3} \sum_{i} \mathbf{E}[X^4] - \frac{2}{n^3} \sum_{i \neq j} \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 \
&\quad + \frac{1}{n^4} \sum_{i} \mathbf{E}[X^4] + \frac{3}{n^4} \sum_{i \neq j} \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 \
\end{align*}
Why there are no sums including indexes concerning k and l?

@MichaelDosier, The reason is that only such terms survive. For example, if you expand $$\sum_{i,j,k}\mathbf{E}[X_i^2 X_j X_k],$$ then any triple $(i,j,k)$ with $j\neq k$ corresponds to either $\mathbf{E}[X^3]\mathbf{E}[X]$ (if $i=j\neq k$ or $i=k\neq j$) or $\mathbf{E}[X^2]\mathbf{E}[X]^2$ (if $i,j,k$ are all distinct), and they are all zero by the assumption $\mathbf{E}[X]=0$. So, only the terms with $j=k$ contribute to the value of the sum, essentially forcing $k=j$ and stripping off of one summation symbol. A similar remark applies to other sums. :)

Enlightening! One more question if I may. Following exactly what you have stated in the previous comment, how it comes that \frac{3}{n^4} \sum_{i \neq j} \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 have \frac{3}{n^4} instead of \frac{2}{n^4} ?
If i \neq j than it means that possible combinations for expectations are X_i * X_k , X_j * X_l and X_i * X_l , X_j * X_k . This turns to be 2* \mathbf{E}[X^2]^2 .
That number 3 in numerator is confusing me...
Thanks once again in advance!

@MichaelDosier, You may also want to include $\mathbf{E}[X_i X_j]\mathbf{E}[X_k X_l]$ :) To put simple, for the index $i$ you can pair it up with any of $j$, $k$, $l$, so we get the factor $3$.

Once again, thank you for a very thoughtful and thorough explanation! I will definitely follow your work on this platform - it keeps me motivated to work harder on my math skills! :)
